# .NET COM usercontrol does not set font or language properly

Tags: vb.net, com, localization, vb6

I have created a COM VB.NET (v3.5 under VS2013) usercontrol which i have included in an old VB6 project. The control communicates with its VB6 host just fine. It works as expected, opens the DB, reads / writes stuff. Everything is OK except one thing, which i'm not sure what it is. It seems i cannot properly set either its font(?) or its language(?) to Greek in order to be able to type Greek characters in a contained textbox.

This usercontrol contains several other .NET controls. Listboxes, buttons and textboxes. I read stuff from DB, set the text property of all those controls to the contents of the database and Greek are shown properly. If i try to switch the O/S language to Greek and type something in a textbox, strange characters are shown instead of the proper Greek ones (i assume from another codepage). I have programmatically changed its font to "[Font: Name=Arial, Size=9, Units=3, GdiCharSet=161, GdiVerticalFont=False]". GdiCharSet=161 is Greek. It should work. And it does work from within the .NET environment or from a test .NET exe. I can type Greek in the textbox. When i try to use it from within the VB6 program, it seems switching to Greek and typing Greek chars is not possible. Loading Greek from DB and showing them is no problem though.

I have also tried setting GdiCharSet to 0, 1, 2 (yup, it did show Symbols as expected) and to change the culture in the usercontrol constructor but no luck:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("el-GR")
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("el-GR")
```

Any ideas someone, what to check / try?

Comment: Forgot to mention: the location, system locale and everything else (formats) in the PC is set to Greek.

Comment: Additional info:

it seems that 

MsgBox(e.KeyChar & " - " & Asc(e.KeyChar)) and 
MsgBox(e.KeyChar & " - " & AscW(e.KeyChar))

inside the textbox's KeyPress event produce different results under the .NET test exe than the VB6 exe.

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong problem, the active keyboard layout is wrong for some reason.  Not telling us where you live and not showing what you type and what characters that produces does not help us help you.  Look at the System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage property.

Comment: You could try setting the *language for non-Unicode programs* to Greek in PC control panel *regional options*?

Comment: Well... as i said in the first comment: "Forgot to mention: the location, system locale and everything else (formats) in the PC is set to Greek"

This is also true for "language for non-Unicode programs". 

Anyway, as you can see below, i managed to find a solution. I don't claim to understand why i had to go this way, but it solves the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow... After spending more hours than i could spare on this matter, i have finally found a solution.

```
Private Sub txtMessage_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtMessage.KeyPress
    If InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.Equals(New Globalization.CultureInfo("el-GR")) Then
        FixKeyChar(e)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub FixKeyChar(ByRef e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    Dim myUnicodeBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.KeyChar)
    Dim myUTF32Bytes As Byte() = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF32, myUnicodeBytes)
    e.KeyChar = ChrW(myUTF32Bytes(1) * 256 + myUTF32Bytes(0))
End Sub
```

I hope it proves to be helpful for some other poor soul messing with these things...